# Validate dynamic generated check boxes using java script

Tags: javascript

I am writing a program in which i retrieve data from database and i get n numbers of rows in the result set . Based on number of rows i have dynamically generated the check box for each row . Now i want to validate this form the scenario goes like this "if user doesn't select any check box" program should generate an error(alert) . I want the js function.

```
while(disciterator.hasNext()) 
        {

           temp=(String)disciterator.next().toString() ;               
            st= new StringTokenizer(temp,"$");          
            enrollment_no = st.nextToken();              


            ExamBean examb = new ExamBean(dbConnVar);




        personal_details=examb.getPersonalDetails(enrollment_no); 

         if(!(personal_details.isEmpty()))
          {
                 st=new StringTokenizer(personal_details,"$");
                firstName1 = st.nextToken();                    
                lastName = st.nextToken();              //  
                address = st.nextToken();                   
                phone = st.nextToken();             //  
                email = st.nextToken();             //  
                gender = st.nextToken();    

                mothers_name = st.nextToken();              //  
                fathers_name = st.nextToken();              //  
                temporary_address =st.nextToken();


         }//end if
         else
         {

         }
```

%>

```
<tr>    
                                <td class="MTTD8" align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="MigrationCHK" id="MigrationCHK" value="<%=enrollment_no%>" onclick="uncheckSelectAll()"></td>
                                <td align="center" class="MTTD2"  > <font size=2>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<%=enrollment_no%> </font></td>
                                <td class="MTTD2" > <font size=2><%=firstName1%> <%=lastName %></font></td>
                                  <td class="MTTD2" ><font size=2><input type="text" name="<%=i%>mcno" /></font></td>
                            </tr>
```

```
  <%    
  i++;
  }
  %>
```

Comment: can you provide generated html (not php) and also your script via which you want validate check boxes?

Comment: im working with jsp nt php ... at the bottom of the form i have provided one button on which i want to call js validation function...


 <input type=submit name=submit value="submit" onclick="validate();"/>

Comment: can you post the code for validate() function?